# When did "Pour out your wrath" become widespread in Haggadot?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

This website quotes Joseph Tabory as saying that the earliest known appearance of Pour Out Your Wrath in a Haggada was in the Machzor Vitry (p. 296) which dates back to around 1200 (See
https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/105867?lang=bi)

Two horrific events/periods (that I mention below) occurred not before or long after that.  I presume there was a lag between the time Pour Out Your Wrath was first put in the Haggada and the time it was widespread.  My question is, when did it become widespread.

There was considerable violence against Jews in the 1300's around the time of the Black Death when some 40% of the population of Europe died. Was the inclusion of "Pour out your wrath" linked to the Bubonic Plague and the contemporaneous extermination, by burning, of most of the Jews in Germany, or did its inclusion become more prevalent then? (See, for example, https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11625662/)

Or was it linked to the First Crusade in the 1000's when the crusaders looted and massacred Jews on their way to liberate Jerusalem from the Moslems. (See, for example, https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/the-crusades/)

Comment: Maybe it was the Romans conquering Jerusalem? Or maybe it was 1929 Hebron massacre? I'm a bit confused why you are proposing these two options in particular

Comment: Any relevant background should be included in the qeustion. I'm also a bit confused if you are asking "when" or "why". We have a question about why already here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81590/759

Comment: @DoubleAA  Are you serious about the Hebron Massacre?